# How to update table with new image data using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form to upload image-path and other image-data. This works well when I choose to upload a new image.

How can I prevent that my image-path is set to blank if I submit my form without choosing a new image?

here is my controller:

```
    function updatewaterpurifier($id)
    {
        $name=$this->input->post('name');

        $this->load->model('user');  
        //$name =  $this->input->post('name');



        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {

        //Check whether user upload picture
            if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
                $new_file_name  = $this->input->post('name');
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf';

            $config['file_name'] = $new_file_name;
            $config['max_size']      = 2048;
            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('picture')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }else{
                $picture = '';
            }
        }else{
            $picture = '';
        }
            //Prepare array of user data
            $userData = array(
                'product_brand'=> $this->input->post('brand'),
                'product_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'product_price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                'product_techno' => $this->input->post('technology'),
                'product_des' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'product_image' => $picture
            );
                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                $this->db->update('products', $userData);
            //Pass user data to model


            //Storing insertion status message.

        }

    //Form for adding user data
        $this->load->model('user'); 
        $this->data['h']= $this->user->editpurifier($id);
        $this->load->view('editwaterpurifier', $this->data, FALSE);



    }
```

Comment: Just to point out you are loading `$this->load->model('user');` twice why not place it in the __construct area of controller that way only have to load it once. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Comment: @Adi Singh: in ur code if u didn’t uploaded the image the ur storing $picture variable with empty and passing this in ur update data. So remove that section the it wil work.

Comment: else part ko remove kar du @Sucharitha

Comment: @AdiSingh: yes that section is not required and then in ur $userData array add the $picture data on conditional basis.

Comment: what i pass i want pass my perivous image path

Comment: @AdiSingh no need to update all the fields. If u didn’t updated then previous value wil be remain as it is

Comment: how to get my uploaded image path in the time of updating images if i dont choose any image @Sucharitha

Comment: @sucharitha the problem is if i update the description portion its update but imge is blank if i don't choose any image

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
 function updatewaterpurifier($id)
    {

        $this->load->model('user');  

        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
        //Prepare array of user data
            $userData = array(
                'product_brand'=> $this->input->post('brand'),
                'product_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'product_price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                'product_techno' => $this->input->post('technology'),
                'product_des' => $this->input->post('description')
            );
         $name=$this->input->post('name');

        //Check whether user upload picture
         if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name']))
          {
            $new_file_name  = $this->input->post('name');
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf';

            $config['file_name'] = $new_file_name;
            $config['max_size']      = 2048;
            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('picture'))
            {
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
                $userData['product_image']=$picture;
            }
           }

        //Pass user data to model
         $this->user->update_purifier($id,$userData);

        }

    //Form for adding user data
        $this->data['h']= $this->user->editpurifier($id);
        $this->load->view('editwaterpurifier', $this->data, FALSE);



    }
```

Model

```
public function update_purifier($id,$userData)
    {

                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                $this->db->update('products', $userData);
    }
```

check product image name contain extention . if not add

```
$ext1 = explode('.',$_FILES['picture']['name']);
$ext2 = array_reverse($ext1);
$extention = strtolower($ext2[0]);
$config['file_name'] = $new_file_name.'.'.$extention;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are updating your table without previous image upload, your variable `$picture=''`. Use that to unset product_image from the array `$userData()`:

```
$userData = array(
  'product_brand'=> $this->input->post('brand'),
  'product_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
  'product_price' => $this->input->post('price'),
  'product_techno' => $this->input->post('technology'),
  'product_des' => $this->input->post('description'),
  'product_image' => $picture
);
if ($picture==''){
  unset($userData['product_image']);
}
```

This removes `product_image` from the array and won't updatinge the image path as blank.